# What does this error message mean and how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I want to encode a string using base64 and then write that to a textfile. I then want to open the textfile and decode its contents (i.e. find the original string). I keep on getting this error message and I am not sure what it means and how to fix my code so that it works.

This is my code so far:

```
text = b"kpahw95R"
compressed = base64.b64encode(text)
print(compressed)
encoded = open("textfile.txt", "w")
encoded.write(str(compressed))
encoded.close()

decoded = open("textfile.txt", "r").read()
decompressed = base64.b64decode(b"decoded")
decoded.close()
print(decompressed)
```

Error message:

```
  File ".../python3.5/base64.py", line 90, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Comment: You're passing literally the (byte)string "decoded" into `b64decode`. I'd think you want *the variable* `decoded` instead...!?

Answer (score 1):

You are decoding the (byte)string `'decoded'`. That's not valid base64 data, and the error tells you it is not the right length to be valid base64, although there are other problems with it; if you added the right padding you wouldn't get your original data back:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64decode(b'decoded')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.5/lib/python3.5/base64.py", line 90, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
>>> base64.b64decode(b'decoded=')
b'u\xe7(u\xe7'
```

You want to pass in the value of the *variable* `decoded`, but you need to actually first encode that data to ASCII for the function to accept it:

```
decompressed = base64.b64decode(decoded.encode('ascii'))
```

Not that you can properly decode the value you wrote to your file. It looks like you tried to convert the `bytes` return value of `base64.b64encode()` to `str` by calling `str()` on it, but that creates a value with `b'...'` around it. You want to *decode* from `bytes` to `str` instead, where Base64 bytes can always be decoded as ASCII.

However, if you were to open your files in *binary* mode, you can write and read `bytes` properly without having to encode or decode:

```
text = b"kpahw95R"
compressed = base64.b64encode(text)
print(compressed)
with open("textfile.txt", "wb") as encoded:
    encoded.write(compressed)

with open("textfile.txt", "rb") as decoded:
    decompressed = base64.b64decode(decoded.read())
print(decompressed)
```

I also used the file objects as context managers (via the `with` statement) so that they are automatically closed for you. Note the addition of `b` in the file modes (`wb` for writing binary, `rb` for reading binary).

Last but not least, encoding to Base64 will *increase* the length of the file; you can hardly call this *compression*; I'd pick different variable names here.